# How do I get a block to fill the remainder of the horizontal space beside a float without using `overflow: hidden` or margins?

Tags: css

The technique I'm most accustomed to in setting a block beside a float is to set the block to have `overflow: hidden;` and it expands to fill the "remaining" horizontal space, assuming it itself doesn't have descendant block elements that make it impossible.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hPBHM/

I'm also familiar with the use of putting the float's width as the margin of the other block. But this isn't suitable 100% of the time, especially when the float's width is not known.

Is the only remaining option to use `table-cell`? Are there other possibilities I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are not more possible solutions with CSS alone.

There is of course, the JavaScript way, if it's critical and width is not known. But that's not a recommended approach for normal cases.